# Regex , Detect all strings preceded with a certain character

Tags: c#, .net, regex

How can I detect in c# all strings that are preceede with  '%'    or '$'    ?

EDIT :

if I have the following string for example :

```
string  test =   "Shipments will cost $150USD , which representes a rise of %34 ."
```

How  can I detect the  `$150USD`   and   `%34`  with regex ?

Comment: yes for example if I  have the string "$150USD"  how can I detect it with regex ?

Comment: check out my answer. Its simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean finding all words, you can use that regex.

```
(?<=\s?)[%$]\w+(?=\s?)
```

So in `Shipments will cost $150USD, which representes a rise of %34.` it will find `$150USD` and `%34`.

The C# code is:

```
String subjectString = "Shipments will cost $150USD, which representes a rise of %34.";
var matches = Regex.Matches(subjectString, @"(?<=\s?)[%$]\w+(?=\s?)");

foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    var value = match.Value;
}
```

Comment: Which Regex function will I have to use ? Regex.Match ?

Comment: `Matches` as you need all matches, not just the first.

Answer (score 1):

As simple as this:

```
string s = "Shipments will cost $150USD , which representes a rise of %34 .";
            var matches = Regex.Matches(s, @"(\$|%)\w+");
            for (int i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(matches[i].Value);
            }
```

Comment: Yes, that's good too (and simpler). You could use a non-capturing group though.